# How to sort a vector to find median and mode?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have to find a way to sort my vector so the numbers are in order to calculate mode and median for the data. I am not sure how to implement it. I tried sorting my vector but when I displayed it, it was still in the order it was before. My task was to get two extreme values of x and calculate 20 increments within those bounds. I then put those numbers into a equation and calculated those values and sent those values to be stored contiguously in a vector. I then have to find max/min, median, mode, range and mean. I have found a way to calculate all except mode and median, which I believe the vector needs to be sorted. Any help on trying to find median and mode as well is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
   double xmin, xmax;
   const int POINTS = 20;
   const double PI = 3.1416;
   double increments;
   int counter = 0;
   double range, mean;
   double total = 0;

   vector<vector<double> > values;

   cout << "Enter in a value for the minimum x value: ";
   cin >> xmin;
   cout << "Enter in a value for the maximum x value: ";
   cin >> xmax;

   if (xmin < 0)
      increments = (abs(xmin) + xmax) / POINTS;
   else
      increments = (xmax - xmin) / POINTS;

   double x = xmin + increments * counter;
   double min = 0.0572 * cos(4.667 * x) + 0.0218 * PI * cos(12.22 * x);
   double max = 0.0572 * cos(4.667 * x) + 0.0218 * PI * cos(12.22 * x);

   cout << setw(15) << "x |" << setw(15) << "f(x)" << endl;
   cout << setw(32) << setfill('-') << " " << endl;
   cout << setfill(' ');
   vector<double> auxiliar;

   while (x <= xmax)
   {
      auxiliar.resize(2);
      auxiliar[0] = x;
      auxiliar[1] = 0.0572 * cos(4.667 * x) + 0.0218 * PI * cos(12.22 * x);

      values.push_back(auxiliar);
      auxiliar.clear();

      if (0.0572 * cos(4.667 * x) + 0.0218 * PI * cos(12.22 * x) > max)
         max = 0.0572 * cos(4.667 * x) + 0.0218 * PI * cos(12.22 * x);

      if (0.0572 * cos(4.667 * x) + 0.0218 * PI * cos(12.22 * x) < min)
         min = 0.0572 * cos(4.667 * x) + 0.0218 * PI * cos(12.22 * x);
      counter++;
      x = xmin + increments * counter;

   }

   for (vector<double> auxiliar : values)
      cout << fixed << showpos << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << auxiliar[0]    << setw(15) << setprecision(4) << auxiliar[1] << endl;

   cout << endl;
   range = max - min;
   for (vector<double> auxiliar : values)
   {
      total += auxiliar[1];
   }

   mean = total / POINTS;

   sort(auxiliar.begin(), auxiliar.end());

   cout << "The maximum value is: " << max << endl;
   cout << "The minumum value is: " << min << endl;
   cout << "The range is: " << range << endl;
   cout << "The mean value is: " << mean << endl;
   cout << "The median value is: " << endl;
   cout << "The mode value is: " << endl;


   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very simple std function that will give you the median of your array: std::nth_element.

Basically, if you want to get your median, you can do this :

```
std::vector<int> v{5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 9, 3};
std::nth_element(v.begin(), v.begin() + v.size()/2, v.end());
std::cout << "The median is " << v[v.size()/2] << '\n';
```

This sample is taken directly from the documentation : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element

To find the mode, you could first sort your vector and the traverse the array. This would be in O(nlog(n)) because of the sorting. Since they are sorted, same elements are next to one another so it's easy to see where there is the most replication.